# Obtain list of applications that can open a file via Terminal?

Tags: macos, command-line, applications

[Anyway to obtain list of Application that can open a file via Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/342229/anyway-to-obtain-list-of-application-that-can-open-a-file-via-terminal?noredirect=1&lq=1) offered a JavaScript which no longer works on macOS 13.1 Ventura. Has anyone updated this script or have a different one?

```
#!/bin/bash 
whatOpens() {
    osascript -l JavaScript <<OSA
        ObjC.import('CoreServices');

        ObjC.deepUnwrap(
                $.LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType(
                        "$1",
                        $.kLSRolesAll
                )
        ).map(x=>Application(x).name())
         .join('\n');
OSA
}

whatOpens "$1"


05:50:10 ~/desktop :whatOpens public.text 
execution error: Error: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...).map(x=>Application(x).n...') (-2700)
05:53:31 ~/desktop :
```